# Why doesn't work sort-object -property or select-object displayName or Format-Table -AutoSize under powershll command in Python when I'm using it?

Tags: python, powershell

i'm tried to execute bellow script but "| sort-object -property DisplayName | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize" unknown in python On the other hand worked correctly in powershell.

```
psh_fnd_postgres=r"Get-ItemProperty  HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | sort-object -property DisplayName | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize"

procs_psh=subprocess.getoutput('powershell %s'%psh_fnd_postgres)
print(procs_psh)

export:
'sort-object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: The error message looks like it comes from cmd.exe shell instead of powershell.exe. Please [edit] the question and show how you invoke a shell session.

Comment: Linux? Try Pascal case: `Sort-Object`.